# Why is setup() executed twice at runtime?

Tags: serial

**Code:**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("hello");
}

void loop() {
}
```

**Output:**

```
hello
hello
```

Why does `hello` print twice?

Comment: Just tried it on my Arduino Uno - only executes once for me. Could it be a residual value in your Serial Monitor

Comment: I considered that so I created a new file, restarted the device and Sketch. Still there...

Comment: Your Arduino must be resetting as it starts 
1 how are you turning it on ? 
2 how are you connecting the serial monitor ?
3 what else is connected ?

Comment: I think it depends on how quickly you start the serial monitor after downloading a program or resetting the Arduino and on operating system buffering.  Ie, your OS (which is what?) buffers a "hello", then you start the serial monitor, which resets the Arduino and produces the second  "hello"

Comment: @jwpat7 That seems the most plausible as sometimes connected lights blink on boot when they are no suppose to.

Comment: jwpat7's suggestion sounds the most plausible. Try opening the IDE's built-in serial monitor before you upload your program. The later IDE's will disconnect their own monitor for the duration of the upload and reconnect it again when the upload is done. That way there will be only one reset and you should see the program output only once.

Comment: If I open my serial monitor, my arduino sometimes resets twice. I wouldn't worry about this.

Comment: Add a 'Serial.println("world"); while(1){};' to your loop, and see if you get just one cycle of loop() per setup().

Comment: @DaveX, I get `Hello
world
Hello
world`, so it looks like the device is resetting every time, like @Gerben's.

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate what type of Arduino you are running this on.  They are not all the same with respect to serial port.

Comment: Since you get hello world twice, it is also entering into the endless loop twice.  Folks are right in that you are seeing two boot-up cycles -- it isn't that the setup is running twice in one poweron/reset cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't, it's displaying the previous message from when you didn't have the Serial Monitor open yet, plus the new message caused by the Arduino resetting from the Serial Monitor being opened.

If you put a longer message in there you'll probably see the first line get cut off and then the full line.